# Syntax error in an if statement

Tags: python

So i'm trying to make a character creator RPG thing for my class, but I'm running into an error

```
#import modules
import random
#define variables
Strength = 0
Health = 0
Wisdom = 0
Dexterity = 0
Pool = 30
choice = None
#Welcome the Player
while choice != 0:
    print ("""
    Welcome to teh CharacterCreator program for RPG's
    What would you like to do?
    0 - Quit
    1 - Assign Point to Atrributes
    2 - Remove Points
    3 - Look at point values
       """);

    choice = input("Choice:")
    print()
    # exit

    if choice == "0":
        print("good-bye.")
    elif choice == "1":
         while Pool > 0:
              print(" You have ",Pool," points left.")
              #Ask which atrribute to chose
              print (""" What would you like to assign points to:
                    Dexterity(1)?
                    Strength(2)?
                    Health(3)?
                    Wisdom(4)?""")
              #assign actions
              pick = input("Choice(1-4):")
              if pick == 1:
                  added = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?")
                  Dexterity += added#I want to add the variable from up there but it give me a syntax error
                  Pool -= added
```

So this is giving me a bit of trouble. I want to add a value from what they input to the variable defined earlier but it give's me a syntax error.

Comment: what is the syntax error you get ?

Comment: You forgot a closing parenthesis. I'll leave it as a task for the asker to find out where.

Comment: Nice try, but somebody already answered :P

Comment: @Kohan As much as it's humorous that someone *did* point out your mistake, you should get accustomed to finding those yourself. (Or even using an IDE that will nicely point it out for you.)

Comment: True... however the IDE told me that the Dexterity was at fault not the line above it, so I assumed.

Comment: Reserve comments for useful explanations of *why* you are doing something rather than paraphrasing the code. And there are some redundant semicolons in your code – they have no place in Python.

Comment: that was just for this question, it is not in the actual code. The semicolons, I have to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line near the bottom:

```
added = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?")
```

You forgot to add a second closing parenthesis at the end.

Comment: I feel stupid now, thanks!